# CentOS: lspci sees wireless device, not seen elsewhere

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, centos

I'm trying to install CentOS 6.8 on a Dell Latitude E6530, and I'm having a hard time getting wireless configured.

The OS can apparently see the wireless card: `lspci | grep "802.11"` yields:
    03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n

But the GUI menu for network connections just shows "Wired Network: disconnected".  There's no other entries in it, nothing about wireless networks at all.  `ifconfig` just shows `em1` and `lo` as interfaces.  And `iwconfig` just shows `lo`, `em1`, and `pan0` (which seems to be for Bluetooth), saying `no wireless extensions` for each.

There's a hardware wifi switch on the side which I have switched to on (I tried it both ways in case red means on, doesn't matter).

Comment: Does [this](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless/Broadcom) help? (Found by googling "centos BCM43228 linux").

Comment: Wow.  It does.  Jeez, setting that up was one of the biggest PITAs I've had in linux in a long time.  Thanks for the find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested by *dirkt* is correct, but it is **specific to CentOS**, whch does not ship the mainline kernel driver for Broadcomm wifi cards, *b43*, for reasons unknown to me. For all other distros, life need not be so complicated. Just for the sake of completeness (*i.e.* there is nothing wrong in *dirkt*'s answer), I would like to show how to install the open source driver *b43* with minimum effort. Please forgive me for being clear rather than terse.

First, the reason why you could not find the wifi interface is that it did not have a suitable driver to operate it. The way to check this is:

```
    # lshw -C network
      *-network UNCLAIMED     
           description: Network controller
           product: Wireless 7265
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           version: 61
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: memory:f1000000-f1001fff
```

The **UNCLAIMED** keyword (I added boldface) shows that no driver is in use at the moment.

But, more importantly, **there is no need to follow the process** suggested by *dirkt*. The Linux kernel already has a module supporting your card, called *b43*: you can read [here](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Supported_devices) that BCM43228 is indeed supported. There is another way to check this, which is to check that your card (Vendor code 14E4, Product code 4359, see ref. above), is supported by either *ssb* or *bcma* (the two modules used by *b43* to handle the internal buses of older/newer BCM chipsets, called respectively *ssb/bcma* like the modules). To do this, we give the command:

```
$ modinfo bcma | grep 4359
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004359sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

which shows that *v14E4p4359* is listed among supported products.

So, why didn't your pc automatically load the *b43* module? Two possibilites:

1. The module *b43* or one of those it depends on is blacklisted. You find all necessary modules again with:

   ```
   $ modinfo b43 | grep depends
     depends:        mac80211,ssb,bcma,cfg80211
   ```

   and then you check whether they are blacklisted by means of

   ```
   $ cd /etc/modprobe.d; grep -nriIl 'b43\|ssb\|bcma\|mac80211\|cfg80211'
   ```

   which returns the list of files where either of the modules is *mentioned*, then you can check the file for a line containing

   ```
   blacklist b43
   ```

   or something similar. Comment out the line, then

   ```
   depmod -ae && update-initramfs -u
   ```

   and you are done.
2. You do not have the relevant firmware. You can check what is required by means of:

   ```
   $ modinfo b43 | grep firmware
   firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
   firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
   firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
   firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
   firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
   firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
   firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
   ```

   The packages containing these firmwares are distribution specific, suitable instructions for many of them can be found [here](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Device_firmware_installation). On my Debian/Ubuntu a quick search,

   ```
   $ apt-cache search b43
     b43-fwcutter - utility for extracting Broadcom 43xx firmware
     firmware-b43-installer - firmware installer for the b43 driver
     firmware-b43legacy-installer - firmware installer for the b43legacy driver
   ```

   shows that *firmware-b43-installer* is the package to be installed. On Arch Linux, the package to install is *b43-firmware*.

Comment: Accepted answer for adding a lot of time-saving context and tips.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Googling "centos BCM43228 linux" finds [this](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless/Broadcom): The BCM43228 and some other drivers are not natively supported by Centos, and you have to download and compile the Broadcom driver from the Broadcom official website as described in the link.